# Where do i specify which values go where in listView using a custom adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm developing a simple application in android.  I have a list of categories (for now), which I would like to display as a list, and then (but this is far away) on click, start another activity with some functions... well, the situation:

my single_list_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <!-- Name Label -->
  <TextView android:id="@+id/category_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:textColor="#43bd00"/>
  <!-- Description Label -->

</LinearLayout>
```

In the main activity here is where I call the adapter and the layout:

```
List<categorie> values = datasource.getAllCategorie();

        // Use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
        // elements in a ListView
        ArrayAdapter<categorie> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<categorie>(this,
            R.layout.single_list_item, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

In the Data source here is where I declare the getAllCategorie:

```
public List<categorie> getAllCategorie() {
            List<categorie> categorie = new ArrayList<categorie>();

            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE,
                allCategorieColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
              categorie categoria = cursorToCategorie(cursor);
              categorie.add(categoria);
              cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // Make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
            return categorie;
          }
```

and finally the categorie.class :

```
public class categorie {
      private long id;
      private String nome;
      private long preferita;

      public long getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public String getNome() {
        return nome;
      }

      public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
      }



      public long getPreferita() {
        return preferita;
    }

    public void setPreferita(long preferita) {
        this.preferita = preferita;
    }

    // Will be used by the ArrayAdapter in the ListView
      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return nome;
      }
    }
```

Currently, if I run the app, it freezes while starting the listview, it makes it completely empty.  I would like to specify where to put each category element, such as the name, or the id or if it is "liked" (get and set Preferita in the categorie.class).

When I started, the adapter part was:

```
ArrayAdapter<categorie> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<categorie>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

and all was magically OK... why is using a default layout OK? again, where do I specify what goes where?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to implement a simple list, there is no problem using a stock `ArrayAdapter`. Android looks at the objects you supply to the adapter, calls `toString()` on those objects and populates a `TextView` with `id=@android:id/text1` with that `String`. It worked "magically" when you used `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` because that layout includes a `TextView` with `id=@android:id/text1`

If you want more control over the layout of each row in your `ListView`, you can use the [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) which lets you map values to certain `Views` in your row layout. Alternatively, you can write your own adapter class by extending `ArrayAdapter`. I recommend writing your own Adapter, as it is both fun and it gives some insight in how lists are populated. [Here's](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) a guide on how to get started with that.